# unable to understand the error when handling Boom error in Jest expect

Tags: jestjs, hapi.js, babel-jest

Following is Jest code to test a utility function (isAuthorized) for a Node code (HapiJs endpoint):

```
**Auth.js:**

 export const isAuthorized = (request, h) => 
 throw Boom.unauthorized('unauthorized') 



**aut.test.js:**
import { isAuthorized } from './Auth';
test('it should return unauthorized', async () => {
  const request = { };


  expect(await isAuthorized(request)).toThrowError(/unauthorized/);
})
```

When execute this test. It gives an error and trace points to location where function throws `Boom.unauthorized('some error')` in fact at `.unauthorized`. The trace is not helpful at all, at least not for me...

Question is what is the best possible way to test a function that throws Boom errors in a Jest expect.

Dependencies include:

```
"hapi": "^18.1.0", 
"jest": "^24.1.0", 
"babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
"regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.1",
"@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",  
"@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.2.0",
```

Comment: what is `isAuthorized`? Show the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Jest's docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html#tothrowerror) you can use `toThrow` with a class as argument, which will check whether the thrown error is an instance of this class. So you can (verified accordingly to [this](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous)):

```js
const Boom = require('boom');
...
// mind `.rejects`
const rejected = expect(isAuthorized(request, h)).rejects;
rejected.toThrow(Boom);
rejected.toThrow('unauthorized');
```

Comment: expect(await isAuthorized(request)).toThrowError(/unauthorized/) or
expect(await isAuthorized(request)).toThrowErrorBoom.unauthorized('Unauthorized')). Both dont work. dnt know why

Comment: @user22197 tried, didn't work indeed, updated the code to something that works.

Answer (score 0):

this, works for me :

```
import Boom from 'boom';

const isAuthorized = (request, h) => {throw Boom.unauthorized('unauthorized');};

test('should throw an error if unauthorized', () => {
const request = {};

expect(() => isAuthorized(request)).toThrowError(Boom.unauthorized('unauthorized'));
    });
```